# anchor tag doesn't work through a different page

Tags: php, html, anchor

I have built a site using foundation and php. On my index.html I am using the foundation scroll feature to scroll to different sections of my page.

on my php page I wanted to set up my navigation links so that they links to their respective section on index.html and I thought this would be easy using anchor tags. however out my links only the first(#second) links through correctly, the rest go straight to the bottom of the index.html page.

I have been searching and I can't find why only one would work and not the others, is there something I am missing? here is my code

//code

```
//Target Section in index.html

    <div class="row">
        <div class="large-8 column large-centered" id="third" data-magellan-target="third">
            <h2 class="heading">Location</h2>
            <div class="border">
                <div id="map">
                    <!--Map Location-->
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div> 

//navigation on php page

                <div class="top-bar-right">
                    <ul class="menu vertical medium-horizontal nav" data-responsive-menu="drilldown medium-dropdown" data-magellan>
                        <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Sales</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Lettings</a></li>
                        <li><a href="index.html#second">Gallery</a></li>
                        <li><a href="index.html#third">Location</a></li>
                        <li><a href="index.html#fourth">Contact Us</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
```

cory this is the code for the scroll feauture

```
/**
 * Magellan module.
 * @module foundation.magellan
 */
!function(Foundation, $) {
  'use strict';

  /**
   * Creates a new instance of Magellan.
   * @class
   * @fires Magellan#init
   * @param {Object} element - jQuery object to add the trigger to.
   * @param {Object} options - Overrides to the default plugin settings.
   */
  function Magellan(element, options) {
    this.$element = element;
    this.options  = $.extend({}, Magellan.defaults, this.$element.data(), options);

    this._init();

    Foundation.registerPlugin(this);
  }

  /**
   * Default settings for plugin
   */
  Magellan.defaults = {
    /**
     * Amount of time, in ms, the animated scrolling should take between locations.
     * @option
     * @example 500
     */
    animationDuration: 500,
    /**
     * Animation style to use when scrolling between locations.
     * @option
     * @example 'ease-in-out'
     */
    animationEasing: 'linear',
    /**
     * Number of pixels to use as a marker for location changes.
     * @option
     * @example 50
     */
    threshold: 50,
    /**
     * Class applied to the active locations link on the magellan container.
     * @option
     * @example 'active'
     */
    activeClass: 'active',
    /**
     * Allows the script to manipulate the url of the current page, and if supported, alter the history.
     * @option
     * @example true
     */
    deepLinking: false,
    /**
     * Number of pixels to offset the scroll of the page on item click if using a sticky nav bar.
     * @option
     * @example 25
     */
    barOffset: 0
  };

  /**
   * Initializes the Magellan plugin and calls functions to get equalizer functioning on load.
   * @private
   */
  Magellan.prototype._init = function() {
    var id = this.$element[0].id || Foundation.GetYoDigits(6, 'magellan'),
        _this = this;
    this.$targets = $('[data-magellan-target]');
    this.$links = this.$element.find('a');
    this.$element.attr({
      'data-resize': id,
      'data-scroll': id,
      'id': id
    });
    this.$active = $();
    this.scrollPos = parseInt(window.pageYOffset, 10);

    this._events();
  };
  /**
   * Calculates an array of pixel values that are the demarcation lines between locations on the page.
   * Can be invoked if new elements are added or the size of a location changes.
   * @function
   */
  Magellan.prototype.calcPoints = function(){
    var _this = this,
        body = document.body,
        html = document.documentElement;

    this.points = [];
    this.winHeight = Math.round(Math.max(window.innerHeight, html.clientHeight));
    this.docHeight = Math.round(Math.max(body.scrollHeight, body.offsetHeight, html.clientHeight, html.scrollHeight, html.offsetHeight));

    this.$targets.each(function(){
      var $tar = $(this),
          pt = Math.round($tar.offset().top - _this.options.threshold);
      $tar.targetPoint = pt;
      _this.points.push(pt);
    });
  };
  /**
   * Initializes events for Magellan.
   * @private
   */
  Magellan.prototype._events = function() {
    var _this = this,
        $body = $('html, body'),
        opts = {
          duration: _this.options.animationDuration,
          easing:   _this.options.animationEasing
        };

    $(window).one('load', function(){
      _this.calcPoints();
      _this._updateActive();
    });

    this.$element.on({
      'resizeme.zf.trigger': this.reflow.bind(this),
      'scrollme.zf.trigger': this._updateActive.bind(this)
    }).on('click.zf.magellan', 'a[href^="#"]', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var arrival   = this.getAttribute('href'),
            scrollPos = $(arrival).offset().top - _this.options.threshold / 2 - _this.options.barOffset;

        // requestAnimationFrame is disabled for this plugin currently
        // Foundation.Move(_this.options.animationDuration, $body, function(){
          $body.stop(true).animate({
            scrollTop: scrollPos
          }, opts);
        });
      // });
  };
  /**
   * Calls necessary functions to update Magellan upon DOM change
   * @function
   */
  Magellan.prototype.reflow = function(){
    this.calcPoints();
    this._updateActive();
  };
  /**
   * Updates the visibility of an active location link, and updates the url hash for the page, if deepLinking enabled.
   * @private
   * @function
   * @fires Magellan#update
   */
  Magellan.prototype._updateActive = function(/*evt, elem, scrollPos*/){
    var winPos = /*scrollPos ||*/ parseInt(window.pageYOffset, 10),
        curIdx;

    if(winPos + this.winHeight === this.docHeight){ curIdx = this.points.length - 1; }
    else if(winPos < this.points[0]){ curIdx = 0; }
    else{
      var isDown = this.scrollPos < winPos,
          _this = this,
          curVisible = this.points.filter(function(p, i){
            return isDown ? p <= winPos : p - _this.options.threshold <= winPos;//&& winPos >= _this.points[i -1] - _this.options.threshold;
          });
      curIdx = curVisible.length ? curVisible.length - 1 : 0;
    }

    this.$active.removeClass(this.options.activeClass);
    this.$active = this.$links.eq(curIdx).addClass(this.options.activeClass);

    if(this.options.deepLinking){
      var hash = this.$active[0].getAttribute('href');
      if(window.history.pushState){
        window.history.pushState(null, null, hash);
      }else{
        window.location.hash = hash;
      }
    }

    this.scrollPos = winPos;
    /**
     * Fires when magellan is finished updating to the new active element.
     * @event Magellan#update
     */
    this.$element.trigger('update.zf.magellan', [this.$active]);
  };
  /**
   * Destroys an instance of Magellan and resets the url of the window.
   * @function
   */
  Magellan.prototype.destroy = function(){
    this.$element.off('.zf.trigger .zf.magellan')
        .find('.' + this.options.activeClass).removeClass(this.options.activeClass);

    if(this.options.deepLinking){
      var hash = this.$active[0].getAttribute('href');
      window.location.hash.replace(hash, '');
    }

    Foundation.unregisterPlugin(this);
  };
  Foundation.plugin(Magellan, 'Magellan');

  // Exports for AMD/Browserify
  if (typeof module !== 'undefined' && typeof module.exports !== 'undefined')
    module.exports = Magellan;
  if (typeof define === 'function')
    define(['foundation'], function() {
      return Magellan;
    });

}(Foundation, jQuery);
```

//EDIT//

I found the issue, it was a jquery plugin i had installed which conflicted with the magellan feature, once removed it worked correctly.

Comment: Does the "foundation scroll feature" involve any JavaScript of any kind? If it does, please include that here as well. In general, we like to see a good [mcve] as described on the [ask] page.

Comment: that's because PHP doesn't support it. You'll need a JS solution.

Comment: *Hold on here cowboy,* you tagged as php but using `.html` files here. Did you in fact instruct your system to treat those as PHP? are you running this off your own PC and did you install a webserver and PHP? if you do have one installed, how are you accessing this as? `http://localhost/file.xxx`? or as `c:///file.xxx`?

Comment: Yowza, where you at here? I'm not going to stand around all day here waiting like someone's personal valet/butler. If you're waiting on a magic answer to appear so that you can comment until the cows come home because it doesn't work, I can tell you right away; it's NOT going to happen. So, either respond to comments, or figure it out for yourself.

Comment: Hi Fred, I am working on a local environment using Xammp, so for the php pages it would be http://localhost/file.xxx. I only tagged as php because I wasn't sure if the fact that I I am linking from a php page is causing the issue. I am confused as to why the gallery link would work and not the others

Comment: @cory Yes it's a feature called magellan, I found the code on their .js file, here it is, however I want to point that I tried it without any foundation classes or attributes (as regular html) and it still didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Your page may not be long enough to achieve the desired result; anchor tags will not make whatever they link to the absolute top item on a page but instead respect page boundaries (you don't have enough material below the tags before hitting the bottom of the page).  My guess is that if you added a few hundred empty p-tags

```
<p></p>
```

to the bottom of your index.html and then tried again you'd get the desired response (this is a good test, not a solution). May want to consider drawers (hide/show) as an alternative.

Comment: I tried something similar with <br> tags before and it didn't work, even without it the target is in the middle of the page and there is 2000px between it and the bottom of the footer

Comment: just built your page on my local (couldn't use empty tags -- stuck a "." in them) and works as expected.  can you paste your code for the anchor destinations?

Comment: I posted it in my original question, is adding a '#' and id name at the end of the link the correct method?

Comment: yes; sorry -- meant the destination code as opposed to the # link

Comment: Are you talking about the section which it links to? it is on my question under "//target section in index.html" 
I tested with two simple html and php pages and the anchor tags work fine so there must be something with foundation that is causing the issue

Comment: fail on my end; didn't realize the target was above the call in the code.  what you've provided still works as expected.  try commenting out your CSS and see if that resolves the functional part.

Answer (score 0):

you can check on the documentation for foundation and check on tabs and deep linking. Deep linking is what is used to navigate and focus on specific sections of a different page or file as it applies to you. Though i just found out that deep linking has not been featured in F6 but available in F5. If you wants to implement this in F6 you have to manually write the script function to do the task.